# How best to achieve this in ansible

Tags: ansible

So I want to deploy a site using the following process using an ansible playbook or playbook(s):

This is the process I need to go through:

1. given a site name and revision number, create a tag called the revision number in the tags branch, unless it already exists, in which case skip this step.
2. connect to the webservers, `svn switch` to the new tags.

So far, so simple. My problem is that step 1 needs to be run locally, and only once. However step 2 needs to be run for each host in the hosts file.

I have achieved this so far, by having two playbooks, For step 1 (playbook1) containing:

```
hosts:127.0.0.1
connection: local
<various tasks>
```

For step 2, playbook2 containing :

```
hosts:all
<various tasks>
```

and then having a "super" playbook which `import_playbook:` the other two.

I'm now finding that I need the variables defined in playbook1 to be accessible in playbook2 which (not entirely unexpectedly) they are not.

The directory layout / practices detailed here: 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout (global_vars/all)
seems like they might do the job, but also seem a bit over the top for what I'm trying to achieve.

What are my options? Or am I (as I suspect) going about his all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run everything with just one `playbook`, and multiple `plays`. On the first `play` you target only your local environment and on the second your group of servers. We need to share the variables generated on the first `play` on the second.

Variables in Ansible are assigned to hosts, so any variables you define on the first `play` would be assigned to `127.0.0.1`. Using the `hostvars` file, we can access all the `hosts` defined on our project as a dictionary, where the value of each `host` is a dictionary with all its `vars`. So, you could read a variable from `localhost` like this: `{{ hostvars["localhost"]["my_var"] }}`.

What I usually do when I need to pass variables to another `play` is define a dummy `host` onto which I append the `vars` I want to share. For example:

```
- name: Create a dummy host to share vars
  add_host:
    name: DUMMY
    my_var: True
```

I can then access the `my_var` variable through the `DUMMY` host like this: `{{ hostvars["DUMMY"]["my_var"] }}`.

And, just a comment to wrap my answer. Instead of using `hosts: all` on the second `play`, create a `group` with the list of all your servers, and then call the `play` on that `group`. It makes it more readable and avoids errors.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks thats the guidance I needed. Its worth mentioning that I ended up with a slightly different solution, but solidly based on your advice non the less. I found that accessing vars_prompt with hostvars['localhost']['var_name'] worked, however variables defined in vars: did not, as such I opted to move the vars to a separate file, and include_var in each play.

Comment: @GeoSword that is an excellent way to do it. If you need dynamic values, you can also generate vars files dynamically, and import them on other plays. I usually also create a `secret.yml` file with `ansible-vault` where I store all the sensitive variables.